# Reset a promise / reuse a promsie

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I've been asking questions about deferred and have come across a problem in my situation.

The user drags file(s) to the window, my file drop class resolves its promise and my main class then acts upon this.

I call my file drop class from my main class:

```
this.fileDrop = new lx.FileDrop();
    this.fileDrop.done(function(files){
        console.log(files);
    });
```

Here is my file drop class:

```
(function(){
"use strict";

var FileDrop = function() {

    return this.init();
};

p.dfd = undefined;

p.init = function() {

    this._initEvents();
    return this.dfd.promise();
};

p._initEvents = function() {

    $(window).on('drop', this.onDrop.bind(this)).on('dragover', this.onDragOver);
};

p.onDrop = function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    this.dfd.resolve(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

};

p.onDragOver = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};

lx.FileDrop = FileDrop;
}(window));
```

On drop the promise is resolved. This works. My issue comes about with multiple drops. The user drags a set of images to screen, the promise resolves with the files. They then drag another set, the promise is already resolved. I know a solution would be to create a new promise each time in the on drop method, but how would I pass this back to the main class each time?

Or is there a way to 'reset' a promise??

Comment: This isn't a case where promises should be used. Just use standard event binding.

Comment: @zzzzBov can you show me an example?

Comment: @zzzzBov your linked answer does not answer my question.

Comment: As they're the same question, the appropriate response is to open a bounty on the existing question.

Comment: @zzzzBov They are not the same, you can't even give me an example of what you suggested.